# wampserver doesn't find some files

Tags: php, css, joomla2.5

I am working on `joomla` template. It has one file `option.css.php`. It has main part of the design but my wamp server does not access that file. How can I make this work?

code for **option.css.php**

```
<?php

     header('Content-type: text/css');
     $color = $_GET['c'];
     $bgimage = $_GET['bg'];
     $mwidth = $_GET['mw'];
     $mstyle = $_GET['ms'];
     $twidth = $_GET['tw'];
     $mdir2 = $_GET['mdir2'];
     $mdir3 = $_GET['mdir3'];
     $logo_mt = $_GET['lmt'];
     $logo_mb = $_GET['lmb'];
     $logo_mh = $_GET['lmh'];
     $ecwid_activate = $_GET['ecwid'];
     $boxed = $_GET['boxed'];

?>
```

**index.php** file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/options.css.php?c=<?php echo str_replace('#','', $color) ; ?>&amp;bg=<?php echo $bgimage; ?>&amp;mw=<?php echo $mwidth; ?>&amp;ms=<?php echo $mstyle; ?>&amp;tw=<?php echo $twidth; ?>&amp;lmt=<?php echo $logo_mt; ?>&amp;lmb=<?php echo $logo_mb; ?>&amp;ecwid=<?php echo $ecwid_activate; ?>&amp;boxed=<?php echo $boxed; ?>&amp;lmh=<?php echo $logo_mh; ?>&amp;mdir2=<?php echo $mdir2; ?>&amp;mdir3=<?php echo $mdir3; ?>" />
```

option.css.php

```
/* Background Color */
.highlight, .button, .button.secondary:hover, #logo h1 span, .top-bar ul > li.has-dropdown .dropdown li a:hover, .footer_social li a, .tp-bullets.simplebullets .bullet.selected, .button.dropdown.split > span, .button.dropdown.split:hover, .button.primary, div.alert-box, .label, .panel.callout, .user-control .notification, .login-modal .close-reveal-modal, .tp-leftarrow:hover, .tp-rightarrow:hover, a.prev:hover, a.next:hover, .content_top, .service-icon img, .service:hover .service-sub, .hover-links a.view-item, .hover-links a.view-image, .content_bottom, div.progress .meter, .accordion-title.active, .ol-type1 > li:before, ul.pagination li.current a, .scrollup:hover, .toggle-view li:hover span, .service-block-icon, .left_pagination:hover, .all_pagination:hover, .right_pagination:hover, .post-date-type1 .post-date-day, .recent-post .post-date-type1 .post-date-day, .option-set li a.selected, .tabs dd.active a, .tabs li.active a, .tabs.vertical dd.active a, .tabs.vertical li.active a, .top-bar ul li.has-dropdown.moved .dropdown li a:hover, .jta-tweet-user-full-name-link, ul.side-nav li.active a, .top-bar ul > li.has-dropdown .dropdown li.active a, .top-bar ul > li.has-dropdown .dropdown li.active ul li.active a, .top-bar ul > li.has-dropdown .dropdown li.active ul li a:hover, .tabs.pill dd.active a, .tabs.pill li.active a {background-color: #<?php echo $color; ?>;}

/* Background Color with !important */
.arrow a:hover, .pricing_plan1:hover .plan_price, .pricing_plan2:hover .plan_price, .pricing_plan3:hover .plan_price, .pricing_plan4:hover .plan_price, .pricing-active .plan_price, .camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul li.cameracurrent > span {background-color: #<?php echo $color; ?> !important;}

/* Text Color */
a, .color, h1 span, h2 span, h3 span, h4 span, h5 span, h6 span, a, a:focus, .top_header a:hover, .top-bar ul > li a.active, .caption.big_color, .service:hover .service-main, .work-item-content h5, .footer a:hover, .footer_bottom a:hover, .type1 a:hover, .type1 li:hover:before, .type2 a:hover, .type2 li:hover:before, .type3 a:hover, .type3 li:hover:before, .type4 a:hover, .type4 li:hover:before, .toggle-view li:hover h2, .article_meta a:hover, .article_meta_type1 a:hover, .article_meta_type2 a:hover, .sidebar-widget a:hover, dl.tabs dd a:hover, dl.tabs dd a:focus, ul.breadcrumbs li.current a, .member-social a:hover, blockquote cite, .lt-ie9 .top-bar ul li a.active, .top-bar ul > li.active a, .work-item-content h4, ul.side-nav li.active ul li.current.active a, .work-item-content h4 a::-moz-selection {color: #<?php echo $color; ?>;}

.top-bar ul > li.active.has-dropdown a.large, .top-bar ul > li.active.has-dropdown a.main, h3 span.color, h4 span.color, h3 i {color:#<?php echo $color; ?>;}

/* Border Color */
.maincontent h3, .top-bar ul > li a.active, .top-bar ul > li:hover a,.work-item:hover, .post-item:hover, .footer h4, ul.tabs-content, .portfolio-item:hover, blockquote, .panel.callout {border-color:#<?php echo $color; ?>}

*::selection      {background-color: #<?php echo $color; ?> ;}
*::-moz-selection {background-color: #<?php echo $color; ?> ;}

/* General Backend Options */
.region3wrap{background:url(../images/backgrounds/<?php echo $bgimage; ?>.png) repeat scroll 0 0 #f1f1f1;} 
.top-bar ul > li.has-dropdown .dropdown li {width: <?php echo $mwidth; ?>px;}
.row {width: <?php echo $twidth; ?>px;}
#logo {margin: <?php echo $logo_mt; ?>px 0 <?php echo $logo_mb; ?>px 0; max-height: <?php echo $logo_mh; ?>px}
body {background:url(../images/backgrounds/<?php echo $bgimage; ?>.png) repeat fixed center 0 #f1f1f1;}
.top-bar ul > li.active a {border-color: #<?php echo $color; ?> !important;}

         <?php if ( $mdir2 == 'left' ) : ?>
.top-bar ul.right .has-dropdown .dropdown {right: auto;left: 0;}
         <?php endif; ?>

         <?php if ( $mdir3 == 'right' ) : ?>
          .top-bar ul.right .has-dropdown .dropdown li.has-dropdown > .dropdown {right: auto; left: 100%;}
         <?php endif; ?>

         <?php if ( $mstyle == 'ipod' ) : ?>
         @media only screen and (max-width: 940px) { .blockmenu {display:none !important;} }
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $mstyle == 'select' ) : ?>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 940px) { .top-bar {display:none !important;} }
        <?php endif; ?>

       <?php if ( $ecwid_activate == '1' ) : ?>
       /* ECWID SStyling Background Color */
html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ProductBrowser-auth-anonim a, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ProductBrowser-auth-logged a, .ecwid-productBrowser-price-value-small, html#ecwid_html body#totop button.ecwid-SearchPanel-button, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-productsList-details div.ecwid-productBrowser-price, html#ecwid_html body#totop button.gwt-Button, html#ecwid_html body#totop #wrapper button.gwt-Button, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ServiceMessage-container div.ecwid-ShadowedPopupPanel-content, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ShadowedPopupPanel-content, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-pager span.ecwid-pager-link-disabled, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Invoice-cell-title, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-ie6-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-ie6-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-ie6-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-placeOrderButton-ie6-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-ie6-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-ie6-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-ie6-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton-ie6-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-ie6-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-ie6-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-ie6-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-ContinueShoppingButton-ie6-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-ie6-up, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-ie6-up-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-ie6-down, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-AddToBagButton-ie6-down-hovering, html#ecwid_html .ecwid-productBrowser-price-value { background:#<?php echo $color; ?> !important; }

       /* ECWID SStyling Color */
          html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid a, html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid a:active, html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid a:visited, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-minicart-link *, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-results-topPanel div.ecwid-results-topPanel-viewAsPanel-link, html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid a, html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid a:active, html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid a:visited, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-categoriesMenuBar td.gwt-MenuItem-selected span.ecwid-categories-category, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-categoriesMenuBar td.gwt-MenuItem-current span.ecwid-categories-category, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-categories-vertical-table-cell-selected span.ecwid-categories-category, html#ecwid_html body#totop table.ecwid-categoriesTabBar table.gwt-TabBarItem-selected span.ecwid-categories-category, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-details-inStockLabel, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-details-inTheBag div, html#ecwid_html body#totop span.ecwid-productBrowser-details-taxValue, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-totalAmount, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-estimationNote span, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-asterisk, html#ecwid_html body#totop .ecwid-productBrowser-relatedProducts .ecwid-productBrowser-productNameLink, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-productsTable-addToBagLink, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-subcategories-categoryName, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-chooseLocationPopup label.ecwid-fieldLabel, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-chooseLocationPopup-deliveryMethodLabel, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-blockTitle, html#ecwid_html body#totop table.ecwid-Checkout-blockTitle div.gwt-Label, html#ecwid_html body#totop table.ecwid-Checkout-blockTitle div.gwt-HTML, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-BreadCrumbs-link-visited, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-BreadCrumbs-link-current, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Invoice-productName, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Invoice-productName a, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Invoice-productName a:active, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Invoice-productName a:visited, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Invoice-Summary-value-price, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-Invoice-Header-OrderId span, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-Invoice-Header-OrderId-long span, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-Invoice-Header-OrderId-very-long span, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-Invoice-Header-OrderId span, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-Invoice-Header-OrderId-long span, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-Invoice-Header-OrderId-very-long span, html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-chooseLocationPopup span.ecwid-shippingOption-rate, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-OrdersList-OrderBox-price, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-OrdersList-OrderBox-totals-price, html#ecwid_html body#totop td.ecwid-OrdersList-OrderBox-header-orderdescr span {color:#<?php echo $color; ?> !important; }

       /* ECWID SStyling Borders Color */
       html#ecwid_html body#totop div.ecwid-Checkout-BreadCrumbs-link-current {border-bottom: 3px solid #<?php echo $color; ?> !important;}
html#ecwid_html body#totop table.ecwid-categoriesTabBar table.gwt-TabBarItem-selected td.tabTopLeft, html#ecwid_html body#totop table.ecwid-categoriesTabBar table.gwt-TabBarItem-selected td.tabTopRight, html#ecwid_html body#totop table.ecwid-categoriesTabBar table.gwt-TabBarItem-selected td.tabTopCenter {border-top: 3px solid        #<?php echo $color; ?> !important;}
      <?php endif; ?>

      /* Boxed Version ON OFF */
      <?php if ( $boxed == '1' ) : ?>
      .main-wrapper {margin: 0 auto; max-width: <?php echo $twidth + 60; ?>px;}
      .region3wrap {background:none;}
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing when it "doesnot(sic) access that file"?

Comment: 1. Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference

Comment: 2. Strict standards: Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically

Comment: Is that the entirety of option.css.php?

Comment: no,it has some css codes

Comment: Please show us that as well.

Comment: Please format that a little better.

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal** complete valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You simply dumped an entire css file here it seems, and besides it seems to be partly minified, answering a question with several pages of code is no fun, so people will simply skip the question.

Comment: is it php-5.3 version ?

Answer (score 1):

Check `short_open_tag = ON` setting in your PHP.INI

Also try to Off url rewriting setting from Joomla ADMIN PANEL